# How can I center bootstrap navbar menus in mobile web?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.navhome {
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.navbar {
    text-align: center;

}

.container-fluid {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active navhome"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I'm having trouble centering bootstrap navbar.
it succeed in desktop browser, but the navigation bar appears vertically in mobile browser. and home button is also strange in mobile. I hope to align it horizontally in mobile web.
Any help would be appreciated! [mobile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbqkF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is causing issues with alignment - `.navhome { padding-right: 50px; }`

**If you want to keep the padding** for big screens only you can add a **[media query](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)**. So this will ensure that the padding is added *only* for screens sizes bigger than 768px.

```
@media (min-width:768px){
  .navhome {
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
}
```

Working example:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .navhome {
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
}

.navbar {
  text-align: center;
}

.container-fluid {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active navhome"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I want to show that space. Is there any other way? and I removed `padding-right: 50px;` but also strange in mobile web. I hope to align it horizontally in mobile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Let me know if you need any other help in this.

Comment: Thank you. I accepted your wonderful answer. and I have one more question. It occurs a vertical menu on the mobile web, but how do you keep it horizontal? I want to straight line menu in mobile web.

Comment: `@media (max-width: 768px){  .nav>ul {    list-style: none;  }
  .nav>li {  display: inline;  }  .nav>li>a {   display: inline;  } }`. Try using this. This should make the list horizontal for screen size less than 768px.